# Sum of squares optimization problem

Tags: matrices, optimization

Suppose I have some data matrix $X$. I would like to find a linear combination of its rows $y = w^{\top}X$ where $w$ is a vector.

I would like choose $w$ so that $\sum_{i=1}^{N} y_{i}^{2}$ is maximized.

How would I solve such optimization problem? I have tested some solvers, which seem to work (e.g. Nelder-Mead). However, I feel I am missing something, in particular if I could use some fast classical technique here. For example, I'm not sure how to formulate a Jacobian/Hessian matrix of this for some solvers that require it. Would it just be $2y$ as entries?

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completely revised answer, which means some of the comments below no longer apply.

You are maximizing $yy^T$, which equals $w^TXX^Tw$. That is equivalent to minimizing $-w^TXX^Tw$, which is a concave quadratic objective. I will presume there are constraints on $w$ according to either A or B as follows:

A. Constraint that $\Sigma w_i =a$. In that case, this is a concave Quadratic Programming problem. Available solvers to find the global optimum include CPLEX, and Gurobi 9.x, as well as general purpose global optimization solvers such as BARON. You don't need to supply any derivatives for any of the listed solvers. The answer for A alsp applies if there are other or additional constraints on $w$, providing that they are all linear constraints (equality and/or inequality).

B. Constraint that $w^tw \le a$. In that case, this is a convex quadratically-constrained concave Quadratic Programming problem. Because the(re is a) global optimum of a concave program with compact constraints is at the extreme of the constraints, there is a global optimum having $w^tw = a$. Nevertheless, from a computational point of view, you are better off providing the problem to the solver as $w^tw \le a$, even if you want $w^tw = a$, because the convex constraint $w^tw \le a$ is easier for solvers to handle. Available solvers include Gurobi 9.x, as well as general purpose global optimization solvers such as BARON. You don't need to supply any derivatives for any of the listed solvers.

You could instead choose to use a local solver which may not find the global optimum, but may be much faster executing. In that case, the gradient of the objective function (based on entering as a minimization problem) is -$X2X^Tw$ and the Hessian is $-2XX^T$

**EDIT**: See comment below by (and thanks to) @Rahul appliacable to the "pure" formulation B. Note however, that the framework provided in B for numerical solution can also handle the incorporation of additional linear or convex or non-convex quadratic constraints, in which case the solution provided by @Rahul would not apply.

Comment: It appears the problem is to *maximize* $yy^T$, which is unbounded since one can always multiply $w$ by a larger and larger scalar.

Comment: @Rahul I misread that as minimized. If it is indeed maximized, you are correct. In either case, the problem is not non-trivially well-formed. If it is "maximized", then the unboundedness could also be fixed by imposition of suitable constraints on $w$. If maximized, and the constraints on $w$ were convex, this would be a concave optimization problem, and if the constraints on $w$ were linear, it would be a concave Quadratic Programming problem, for which specialized solvers are available, but the run-time can be long to find a global optimum.

Comment: Yes, I would like to do maximization here. Maybe $w$ or its square could sum to a constant for example, to have a constraint avoiding the blow-up

Comment: I will revise my answer to cover both cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is very helpful! Many pointers for further study. I'll get started right away and try the software you suggested

Comment: Btw, may I further ask how the gradient and Hessian can be found?

Comment: That is standard matrix calculus https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus

Comment: @mmh, Mark: If you want to maximize the length of $w^TX$ subject to $w^Tw\le a$, then there is a closed-form solution: the optimal $w$ is proportional to the left singular vector of $X$ corresponding to the largest singular value.

Comment: @Rahul Thanks, that is a very interesting point. Having now studied my problem for several days, I think I need to add one more constraint, which is $(\mathbf{w^{\top}X})_{i} < 1$ for each $i$. It would be very nice if I could do this still via SVD but keep the new constraint, do you think something like that would be possible?

Comment: mmh Note that both my approaches A and B could handle the incorporation of additional linear constraints.  I will defer to @Rahu on the SVD approach, except to note that if the SVD solution happens to satisfy the additional constraint, then it is optimal for the problem in which the additional constraint is included.

Comment: @MarL.Ston My name continues to be Rahul with an L.

Comment: @Rahul Sorry, copy and paste error missed the last character.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone In the last paragraph, does the Hessian $-2\mathbf{XX}^{\top}$ come from writing the objective function in quadratic form (it has a $1/2$ as a scalar multiplier)? Should the gradient then be in fact $-\mathbf{XX^{\top}w}$? (i.e. the other $\mathbf{X}$ is missing from the answer) Or is it that I just fail to see something?

Comment: That was a typo in the gradient, missing a "2", which I have now corrected.  I wrote out the gradient (now corrected) and Hessian corresponding to the objective function as you wrote.  Often, a factor of 1/2 is used, for the purpose of eliminating the "2" in the Hessian.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Thanks, but isn't the other $\mathbf{X}$ also missing? I am reading a book on quadratic programming, and it says the gradient would be $\mathbf{A}$ if the objective function is $-\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{w^{\top}Aw}$. Here we would have $\mathbf{XX^{\top}}$ as $\mathbf{A}$. I also get an incorrect dimensions error if I try $-2\mathbf{X}^{\top}\mathbf{w}$ in a numerical solver

Comment: You are correct. Yet another typo, now corrected, from rushing my post. Sorry. But actually, it has probably worked out for the best for you as it got you to figure out and understand things. Now you understand it better.