# Sum of squares optimization with a cut-off (Quadratic programming problem)

Tags: matrices, optimization, matrix-decomposition, quadratic-programming

I recently asked about an optimization problem, which turned out to be a quadratic programming problem. Specifically, I wanted to minimize the objective function $$-\mathbf{w^{\top}XX^{\top}w}$$ with the constraint $||\mathbf{w}|| = 1$. For this problem the optimal solution is proportional to the left singular vector corresponding to the largest singular value.

After analyzing the problem for two weeks, and learning a lot about quadratic programming, I came to the conclusion that I must modify my original problem. Specifically, I would like to maximize

$$f(\mathbf{y}) = \begin{cases}\sum_{i}y_{i}^{2}, \quad &y_{i}^{2} < c\\ 0,\quad &y_{i}^{2} \geq c\end{cases}$$

where $\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{w^{\top}}\mathbf{X}$ and $c$ is some constant value. So, unlike previously, there is a cut-off in the function.

Is it still possible to solve this via SVD (or find other closed-form solution)? Alternatively, could I rewrite the problem so that the piecewise part becomes a constraint to the problem?

The previous question is available [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3540043/sum-of-squares-optimization-problem), which might be helpful for context.

Comment: You are using $i$ in two different ways.  I think you meant $$f(\mathbf{y})=\sum\limits_{i: y_i^2<c} y_i^2.$$

Comment: Are you sure about the discontinuity? A more typical setup would be that the quadratic function saturates, i.e. the function value is $c^2$ for $y_i^2\geq c$.

Comment: @RobPratt, Yes, indeed, that is what I meant.

Comment: @JohanLöfberg That might actually work as well! Would it be easier to solve? Though, I am fairly sure about the cut-off, at least based on everything I have done on this problem so far.

Comment: No, not easier, you just showed an odd objective where the cost increases up to a certain limit, and then abruptly drops to having no cost. Hard to see where one would want such behavior.

Comment: @JohanLöfberg It is just that $y_{i}^{2} \geq c$ is not really no longer well-defined in my problem. However, since the data in matrix $\mathbf{X}$ is noisy, the optimal $\mathbf{w}$ seems to be such that some $y_{i}^{2}$ will be larger than $c$

Comment: Saw now that you are maximizing the definite function, so ok then it makes sense to have zero cost (or perhaps better said zero profit) from those $y_i$, to guide the solver to absolutely not pick such a $y_i$. Still the problem is hard, and with this discontinuous objective, it is badly conditioned too.

Comment: @JohanLöfberg Can you explain why it is badly conditioned and what it means? I am still early in the learning process

Comment: An epsilon change in $y_i$ cause the objective term to go from $c$ to 0

Comment: @JohanLöfberg Thanks! Hmm, maybe the discontinuity could be replaced with something that goes to zero more smoothly, if it would be still possible to keep this as a quadratic programming problem / have closed-form solution.

Comment: You still have a terrible nonconvex program, You're not getting past that.